# I need help to dynamically add an onload function to the body tag

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, nested

I am having trouble having to if statements on my body tag. The if statement i currently have is wordpress function:

```
<?php echo is_single() ? "<body class='single'>" : "<body>" ; ?>
```

This works fine. The problem is on 1 page I need to have "". 
So what I did was wrap this in another if statement like so:

```
<?php if(is_page('map')) : ?> 
<?php echo "<body onload="initialize()">" ; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php echo is_single() ? "<body class='single'>" : "<body>" ; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Apparently my syntax is wrong on the 2nd line, but I can't see why?

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong? Or is there an easier way to achieve this in wordpress?

Thanks in advance, 
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In strings you can't have double quotes as delimiter and inside the string, you need to escape them.

```
<?php 
if(is_page('map')):
   echo '<body onload="initialize()">';
else:
   echo is_single() ? "<body class='single'>" : "<body>";
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Brilliant, cheers mate.
It seems really simple now I look at it. Think I may to get more sleep haha.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the alternative `if:else:endif;` syntax there ?

Comment: @AJweb, darn you're right. Haven't seen it this way before. I'll adjust my answer

Comment: By the way, the main problem with my code in the first place was the double quote. Very simple mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<?php echo "<body onload=" . initialize() . ">" ; ?>
```

Note the dots used for concatenation.

Edit: This is presuming initialize is your php function. If not, use single quotes like this:

```
<?php echo '<body onload="initialize()">' ; ?>
```

Comment: Probably `initialize()` is a javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scape the double quotes on your string on the second line:

```
<?php echo "<body onload=\"initialize()\">" ; ?>
```

or better still:

```
<?php echo '<body onload="initialize()">' ; ?>
```